# How to pass a two-dimensional array as a function argument in Etherscan?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, etherscan, bscscan

I need to call a contract function from Etherscan that takes a 2d array as an argument, namely: `foo (address[][])`.

I have tried every thinkable way to call the function with no success. Etherscan displays error

```
expected array value (arg="foo", coderType="array", value="0xabscde1234567887654321abcde")
```

What is the correct way to call the function?

Answer (score 0):

This works with Remix, but not etherscan. No quotes necessary. Should work for addresses too.

```
[[1,2],[6,9],[2323,10]]
```